# How to make a fetched result fit into a model?

Tags: php, laravel, data-binding

Let's say I do a

```php
$response = Http::get('http://example.com');
$i_want_to_be_a_model = $response->json();
```

And I have a `\App\Models\Example` model.

How can I make the `$i_want_to_be_a_model` to be an `Example` model?

I want to do this, because I want to add a method `statusText()` to the model, that is not part of the result.

```php
class Example extends Model {
   
  // ..
  public string $statusText;
  public int $status;


  public function statusText() {
    switch ($this->status) {
      case 100:
        $this->statusText = "foo";
        break;
      //..
      default:
        $this->statusText = "bar";
    }
  }
}
```

If there is a more elegant way if doing this, please let me know.

Comment: Does `$example = new Example($response->json());` work?

Comment: Oh is it really that simple? I tried it but this is just creating an `Example` model with the properties that have default values, like if I'd have `public int $status = 100;` the `$example` will have status 100 no matter what status is coming from the request

Comment: Typically you don't define properties like `public int $id`, etc. on Models, as they are  dynamically created from the DB row they represent. For this model, since it doesn't have a DB equivalent, you might need to add and modify the `__construct()` method to pass those params during instantiation, like `public function __construct(array $attributes) { foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) { $this->{$key} = $value; } });` (or similar; play with that code a bit). I've used "no-DB Models" in the past, since they are super useful classes, but it requires some tweaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `helper` function or a **Factory** class to create objects of `Example` class.

For eg:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Factories;

use App\Models\Example;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class ExampleFactory
{

    public function __construct(array $attributes)
    {
        $example = new Example;

        $fields = Schema::getColumnListing($example->getTable());

        foreach($attributes as $field => $value) {
            if(in_array($field, $fields) {
                $example->{$field} = $value;
            }
        }

        return $example;
    }

    public static function makeFromArray(array $attributes)
    {
        return new static(... $attributes);
    }
}
```

Then you can use the Factory as

```php
// use App\Factories\ExampleFactory;

$response = Http::get('http://example.com');

$example = ExampleFactory::makeFromArray(json_decode($response->json(), true));

//Now you can do whatever you want with the instance, even persist in database
$example->save();
```